# Data Table Server Side Processing

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatable, datatables

Hi i am using datable server side processing,

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#TABLE").dataTable({
            "bProcesing" : true,
            "bServerSide" : true,
            "bLenthChange" : false,
            "iDisplayLength" : 10,
            "bSort":false,
             "bFilter": true,
            "sAjaxSource" : "/easdaspp/abc",
            "aoColumns" : [
            {
            "sTitle" : "Organization Name",
            "mData" : "organizationName"
            },
            {
            "sTitle" : "Delete",
            "sDefaultContent" : '<a href="abc/{organizationId}" >Delete</a>'
            }],
            "fnServerData" : function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
            $.ajax({
            "dataType" : 'json',
            "type" : "GET",
            "url" : sSource,
            "data" : aoData,
            "success" : fnCallback
            });
            },
            "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers"

            });// dataTable
             });
```

How do i get organizationId value in anchor tag 
like this

```
     "sDefaultContent" : '<a href="abc/{organizationId}" >Delete</a>'
```

should be

```
       <a href="abc/1" >Delete</a>
```

so on for every rows, the value of url should change according to us

Comment: read about js replace and regex. I don't see any difficulties

Comment: `$("a").attr("href").trim().replace(/{value}/, jsonResponseValue);` and then set this value into gref attribute like this `$("a").attr("href", newHrefValue);`

Comment: i mean how do i get jsonResponseValue i using datatable see my modefied code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution using mRender we can sort this out

```
{"mData" : "organizationId",
              "mRender": function ( data, type, full ) {
              return '<a href="'+data+'">Download</a>';
             }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I use another method see for yourself
this is the server side script of the old datatables

```
static function data_output($columns, $data) {
    $out = array();

    for ($i = 0, $ien = count($data); $i < $ien; $i++) {
        $row = array();

        for ($j = 0, $jen = count($columns); $j < $jen; $j++) {
            $column = $columns[$j];
            if ( $aColumns[$i] == "cId" ){
            /* Special output formatting for 'cId' column */

            $row[] = '
            <div id="trigger">
              <a target="_blank" title="Click to make Payment" href="viewDetails.php?cId='.$aRow[$aColumns[$i]].'">
                <img src="images/icons/color/rupee.png" />
              </a>
            </div>
            ';
           }
        }
     }
```